# TextBox mirrors another Textbox contents

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I have 3 textbox. textBox1, textBox2, and textBox3. I want to display whatever number I typed in textBox1 to texBox3.

The problem is whenever I backspace or delete all the items in textBox1 the first number I typed still lingers in textBox3.

Goal: If textbox1 is empty then textbox3 has to be empty to.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             double num1, num2 = 0;

             double result;

             num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
             num2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
             result = num1 + num2;
             textBox3.Text = result.ToString();


             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
             {
                 textBox3.Text = "";
             }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {

         }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDouble` throws on an empty string.

When `textBox1.Text` or `textBox2.Text` is empty, an exception occurs, you swallow it in the empty `catch` and the rest of the method does not execute.